# iOS google maps add multiple pins on map

Tags: ios, google-maps

I use following code to add pins to map on google map view in my app:

```
 [self.vm.arrValues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(GeoObject*  _Nonnull go, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {


        CLLocationCoordinate2D circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(go.latitude, go.longitude);
        GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:circleCenter
                                                 radius:1000];
        circ.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] ;
        circ.map = _mapView;
        circ.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    }];
```

Problem is, i have actually 1337 pins, so it's kind of slowly and laggy. Is there any way to speed up process?

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem by following:

```
[self.vm.arrValues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(GeoObject*  _Nonnull go, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        GMSGroundOverlay *overlay = [GMSGroundOverlay groundOverlayWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(go.latitude,go.longitude) icon:self.circImg zoomLevel:12 ];
        overlay.map = _mapView;

    }];
```

Because filling colour was causing performance issues i found a way to simply display image with specific coordinates.